# Quota exceeded log in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to access quota exceeding log in GCP?

This is very useful when a product using your GCP account resources doesn't have proper logging indicating which specific quota was exceeded, as well as when you don't know if that's a quota issue or not, altogether.

Comment: You can use Cloud Monitoring to monitor your quotas and send an alert. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics A recommender also exists https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/service-limit-quota-recommender

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere I was just adding the same as an answer along with a few extra lines from the docs.

Comment: @inteloid are your queries addressed revert back if you are still having some queries so that we can help you..

Answer (score 0):

Like `guillaume blaquiere` said you can monitor resource quota utilizations using google cloud monitoring, you can create charts or create alerts and also use error notifications for monitoring quota limits. Some services won’t support quota related metrics, go through this [**official documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#checking_metric_support) for more information on the services that support and don’t support quota-related metrics.

As per this [**official documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics) **Cloud Monitoring** manages quota in two ways:

> **Consumer quota:** For this type of quota, the monitored resource is consumer_quota. The metrics for this resource are a subset of the
> service runtime metrics.
>
> **Resource-specific quotas:** Some services provide monitored resources that have resource-specific metrics for quotas. These metric
> types appear in groups of three and follow a naming format:
>
> - service/quota/quota-type/exceeded
> - service/quota/quota-type/limit
> - service/quota/quota-type/usage
>
> For example, Compute Engine has the compute.googleapis.com/VpcNetwork
> resource. The quota-related metrics associated with this resource are
> the compute.googleapis.com/quota subset of the compute metrics. There
> are three metric types related to the "instances per VPC network"
> quota:
>
> - quota/instances_per_vpc_network/exceeded
> - quota/instances_per_vpc_network/limit
> - quota/instances_per_vpc_network/usage

Go through **Chart and monitor quota metrics** documentation(second hyperlink) for more information on how to configure monitoring metrics for monitoring quota utilizations.